# Groovy CompileStatic on Android messes up Groovy Truth

Tags: android, groovy, libgdx, truthiness

In Groovy it is possible to test collections for null and empty simply by placing the variable by itself inside if like:

```
def collection = [ 'test' ]
if(!collection) {
  //Collection is either null or empty, handle exceptional business here
}
```

However upon placing `@CompileStatic` on the class which contains code like this, it stops working (but only on Android) with an error:

```
02-16 20:49:03.837: E/AndroidRuntime(9013): org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.asBoolean() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

This does not seem to occur when running the desktop version.

To give more context. This is a generated LibGDX project with three projects (-core, -desktop, -android) where the -core project has been converted to a groovy project. The -core project is referenced, and a dependency of both -desktop and -android projects

Desktop version works without any issues regardless whether the classes are annotated with `@CompileStatic`annotation, and Groovy Truth is properly recognized.

On android on the other hand, the aforementioned error occurs.

I am not using the grooid library because the project which is converted to groovy is shared between both desktop and android.

If it's of any worth, here are the contents of `build.gradle` on the project level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.5'        
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'CastleShuffle'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.4'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-04'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android" 
    //apply plugin: "groovyx.grooid.groovy-android"   

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {        
        compile project(":core")            
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    //    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.0:grooid' //Adding this causes a Dex exception where groovy class Bindable is referenced multiple times
    //    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "groovy"    

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the "grooid" version of Groovy for all your modules, otherwise you will have code generated that uses a runtime targetted at normal JVMs. Using '2.4.1-grooid' for all your modules should be good I think.

Comment: There seem to be issues with grooid repository paths, `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.1:grooid'` in gradle produces a different path than the real dependency path so I can't really test it. When i figure out what's wrong and how to fix it I'll try your solution and distribute the bounty appropriately. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are including the groovy-all dependency from core into your android project. This needs to be excluded since groovy-all and grooid jars can't be compiled together.